# Can gcc4.8 link the library that is compiled by gcc 4.9?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14

I'm trying to build folly on centos 7 which the GCC version is 4.8.3.But it require GCC 4.9+ to support the c++14 features.Is it OK to compiled on GCC 4.9 and linked and used in GCC 4.8?

Comment: How are you going to link with the newer runtime support libraries with the older version of GCC?

Comment: use GCC 4.9 to compile it and used on another computer that GCC version is lower than 4.9.

Comment: Either copy libstdc++ and use an `$ORIGIN`-based rpath, or (ick) use static linking everywhere.

Comment: Is it not possible to upgrade, or install a parallel new version of GCC on centos?

Comment: Maybe I need devtoolset-3.